# Реализация табличной модели с возможностью удалённой синхронизации

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Во фреймворке Qt имеется класс `QSqlTableModel`. Интерес вызывает наличие в нём такой функциональной возможности, как отложенная синхронизация с таблицей БД. Речь идёт о флаге `EditStrategy` со значением `OnManualSubmit`.

Пользователь приложения вносит некоторые изменения в модель таблицы, а та уже по какому-либо событию, например, нажатию кнопки, заносит новые данные, изменяет имеющиеся или удаляет ненужные непосредственно в самой БД.

Мне потребовался в целом идентичный механизм, но функционирующий через сеть и соответственно без прямого подключения к базе данных. Однако в Qt нет реализации такой модели, что предоставляла бы обозначенную возможность.

`QStandardItemModel` сохраняет изменения сразу, требует `QtGui` из-за поддержки рисования иконок (в моём случае это лишнее), да и в целом она заточена скорее под "дерево", нежели таблицу.

Остаётся `QAbstractTableModel`, у которой даже по названию можно догадаться, что это лишь самый базис, и она не готова к использованию, как говорится, из коробки.

Понимаю, что можно унаследовать эту самую `QAbstractTableModel`, переопределить соответствующие виртуальные методы, но сложность момента в том, что, например, только что внесённые пользователем строки, если он их удаляет, должны быть удалены из редактируемой модели, тогда как существующие в исходной таблице - лишь отмечены на удаление. При редактировании каждой ячейки нужно сохранять предыдущее значение, если вдруг потребуется откат. А добавленные строки должны быть впоследствии отправлены на синхронизацию при подтверждении на сохранение изменений, либо удалены при откате.

Как создать такую модель, которая будет учитывать вносимые пользователем изменения и предоставлять возможность отката к первоначальному состоянию по той же схеме, как это реализовано в `QSqlTableModel`?

Comment: Так посмотрите, как устроена QSqlTableModel, исходники же есть.

Comment: @gbg , я смотрел, но там для меня, если честно, сам чёрт ногу сломит. Я также не уверен, что нужно именно в наследнике `QAbstractTableModel` всё реализовывать, и может быть будет лучше, если задействовать прокси модель. Как-то через её фильтрацию. Подумал, что если кто сталкивался с подобным, то направит по пути наименьшей болезненности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Остановился на варианте наследования от `QAbstractTableModel` с использованием т.н. постоянных индексов, предоставляемых `QPersistentModelIndex`. Постоянные индексы автоматически меняют сохранённые у себя порядковые номера строк и колонок в том случае, если производилось добавление и/или удаление любых других строк и колонок таблицы.

Это по сути весь ответ на мой вопрос и идея. Далее следует необязательное "краткое" описание реализации такой табличной модели.

---

Начну с хранилища данных, с которым модель будет взаимодействовать. Для табличной модели нужна матрица. Класс матрицы может быть любой, лишь бы удовлетворял возможности добавления и удаления строк и колонок:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix() : _rows(0), _cols(0) {}
        Matrix(int rows, int cols) : _rows(rows), _cols(cols), _cells(rows*cols) {}
        ~Matrix() {}

        int rows() const {return _rows;}
        int cols() const {return _cols;}

        void insertRows(int row, int cnt) {
            if(_rows >= row && row >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                if(_cols == 0) _cols = 1;
                _cells.insert(_cols * row, _cols * cnt, T());
                _rows += cnt;
            }
        }

        void removeRows(int row, int cnt) {
            if(_rows >= (row+cnt) && row >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                _cells.remove(_cols * row, _cols * cnt);
                _rows -= cnt; if(_rows == 0) _cols = 0;
            }
        }

        void insertCols(int col, int cnt) {
            if(_cols >= col && col >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                if(_rows == 0) _rows = 1;
                for(int row = 0; row < _rows; ++row)
                    _cells.insert(pos(row,col)+(row*cnt), cnt, T());

                _cols += cnt;
            }
        }

        void removeCols(int col, int cnt) {
            if(_cols >= (col+cnt) && col >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                for(int row = 0; row < _rows; ++row)
                    _cells.remove(pos(row,col)-(row*cnt), cnt);

                _cols -= cnt; if(_cols == 0) _rows = 0;
            }
        }

        const T &data(int row, int col) const {return _cells[pos(row,col)];}
        T &data(int row, int col) {return _cells[pos(row,col)];}

        void clear() {_rows = 0; _cols = 0; _cells.clear();}

    private:
        int _rows, _cols;
        QVector<T> _cells;

        int pos(int row, int col) const {return _cols * row + col;}
};
```

У таблиц имеется особенность - заголовки, горизонтальный и вертикальный. Очень удобно значения заголовков хранить прямо в матрице, тем более что типы значений у обычных ячеек и ячеек заголовков как правило одни и те же:

```
typedef QMap<int,QVariant> Cell;
```

Данные каждой ячейки - это по сути ассоциативный массив, где ключом является флаг `Qt::ItemRole` (в `int` его определяют обычно с целью переносимости), а значением - произвольный тип данных.

Если для заголовков зарезервировать нулевую по индексу колонку и нулевую по индексу строку матрицы, то впоследствие скажется необходимость в постоянном учитывании этого фактора, что может затруднить написание кода и его отладку. Проще сразу этот момент предусмотреть и, унаследовав класс матрицы отдельным классом, производить смещение (offset) на лету. Также, удобно выделить доступ к каждому типу заголовка (горизонтальный / вертикальный) в отдельные методы:

```
template<class T>
class Table : public Matrix<T> {
    public:
        Table() : Matrix<T>(1,1) {}
        Table(int rows, int cols) : Matrix<T>(rows+1,cols+1) {}
        ~Table() {}

        int rows() const {return Matrix<T>::rows()-1;}
        int cols() const {return Matrix<T>::cols()-1;}

        void insertRows(int row, int cnt) {Matrix<T>::insertRows(row+1, cnt);}
        void removeRows(int row, int cnt) {Matrix<T>::removeRows(row+1, cnt);}

        void insertCols(int col, int cnt) {Matrix<T>::insertCols(col+1, cnt);}
        void removeCols(int col, int cnt) {Matrix<T>::removeCols(col+1, cnt);}

        const T &headerRowData(int row) const {return Matrix<T>::data(row+1, 0);}
        T &headerRowData(int row) {return Matrix<T>::data(row+1, 0);}

        const T &headerColData(int col) const {return Matrix<T>::data(0, col+1);}
        T &headerColData(int col) {return Matrix<T>::data(0, col+1);}

        const T &data(int row, int col) const {return Matrix<T>::data(row+1, col+1);}
        T &data(int row, int col) {return AMatrix<T>::data(row+1, col+1);}
};
```

Объявление класса модели ничем особым не отличается от обычно используемых в Qt. Всё, что необходимо - это переопределить добавление и удаление строк, а также внесение и получение данных для ячеек таблицы и её заголовков. Что касаемо добавления и удаления колонок - реализация этого функционала в рассматриваемой задаче не имеет особого основания, поскольку таблицы БД редко меняют свой колоночный состав, да и производится это обычно вне приложения.

Файл **tablemodel.h**:

```
#include <QtCore/QAbstractTableModel>

class TableModelPrivate;

class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit TableModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        explicit TableModel(int rows, int cols, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        virtual ~TableModel();

        virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
        virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;

        virtual bool insertRows(int row, int count
            , const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
        virtual bool removeRows(int row, int count
            , const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());

        virtual QVariant headerData(int section
            , Qt::Orientation orientation
            , int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

        virtual bool setHeaderData(int section
            , Qt::Orientation orientation
            , const QVariant &value
            , int role = Qt::EditRole);

        virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;

        virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index
            , int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

        virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex &index
            , const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);

    public slots:
        virtual void submitAll();
        virtual void revertAll();

    private:
        QScopedPointer<TableModelPrivate> _d;
};
```

Файл **tablemodel.cpp**:

```
#include <QtCore/QDataStream>
#include <QtCore/QSet>

#include "tablemodel.h"

typedef QMap<int,QVariant> Cell;

class TableModelPrivate : public Table<Cell> {
    public:
        TableModelPrivate() : Table<Cell>() {}
        TableModelPrivate(int rows, int cols) : Table<Cell>(rows,cols) {}

        QSet<QPersistentModelIndex> _inserted_pmis;
        QSet<QPersistentModelIndex> _edited_pmis;
        QSet<QPersistentModelIndex> _removed_pmis;

        QHash<QPersistentModelIndex,Cell> _edited_cells;
};
```

Приватный класс модели `TableModelPrivate` нужен, чтобы "не высовывались наружу" классы матрицы и таблицы. Впрочем, это дело каждой конкретной реализации и её специфики.

Постоянные индексы, которые будут хранить номера строк собраны в отдельные группы по типу производимого пользователем действия, как то добавление строки, редактирование хотя бы одной ячейки в строке и удаление строки.

Последним идёт хэш, предназначенный сохранять вновь введённые пользователем значения в ячейки. Редактирование одной и той же ячейки до подтверждения изменений может производиться не единожды, а значит ранее введённое значение можно без проблем затереть новым, при этом не трогая оригинальное, находящееся в хранилище модели.

Далее, основной класс модели:

```
TableModel::TableModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
    , _d(new TableModelPrivate()) {}

TableModel::TableModel(int rows, int cols, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent), _d(new TableModelPrivate(rows,cols)) {}

TableModel::~TableModel() {}

int TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return (parent.isValid() == false) ? _d->cols() : 0;
}

int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return (parent.isValid() == false) ? _d->rows() : 0;
}
```

Вставка строк в модель осуществляется стандартным образом за исключением момента с вынесением постоянных индексов (если строк вставляется несколько) в отдельный список в цикле:

```
bool TableModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent) {
    if(!parent.isValid() && rowCount(parent) >= row && row >= 0 && count > 0) {
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
        _d->insertRows(row, count);

        for(int r = row, rs = row + count; r < rs; ++r) {
            QPersistentModelIndex pmi(this->index(r,0,parent));
            _d->_inserted_pmis.insert(pmi);
        }

        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Удаление строк немного сложнее, поскольку требует определения типа действия, возможно произведённого ранее над строкой:

```
bool TableModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent) {
    if(!parent.isValid() && rowCount(parent) >= (row+count)
        && row >= 0 && count > 0) {

        for(int r = row, rs = row + count; r < rs; ++r) {
            QPersistentModelIndex pmi(this->index(r,0,parent));

            // Если строка была ранее вставлена,
            // то просто удаляем её из модели вместе
            // с соответствующим ей постоянным индексом.
            if(_d->_inserted_pmis.contains(pmi)) {
                _d->_inserted_pmis.remove(pmi);
                beginRemoveRows(parent, r, r);
                _d->removeRows(r,1);
                endRemoveRows();

            }

            // Если хотя бы одна из ячеек строки ранее редактировалась,
            // то, не трогая строку в модели, лишь удаляем
            // соответствующий постоянный индекс редактирования.
            // Также производим удаление значений ячеек этой строки,
            // сохранённых ранее в качестве редактированных.
            else if(_d->_edited_pmis.contains(pmi)) {
                _d->_edited_pmis.remove(pmi);

                QMutableHashIterator<QPersistentModelIndex,Cell>
                    itr(_d->_edited_cells);
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    itr.next();
                    const QPersistentModelIndex &pmi2 = itr.key();
                    if(pmi2.row() == pmi.row()) itr.remove();
                }

                _d->_removed_pmis.insert(pmi);
                emit headerDataChanged(Qt::Vertical, r, r);

            }

            // Если же строка была отмечена на удаление,
            // то добавляем ссылку на неё в отдельный список индексов.
            else {
                if(!_d->_removed_pmis.contains(pmi)) {
                    _d->_removed_pmis.insert(pmi);
                    emit headerDataChanged(Qt::Vertical, r, r);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Возврат значения ячейки заголовка. Для вертикального, не трогая данные модели, возвращаем спецсимволы, если строка добавлялась и редактировалась - "*", а также "!", если строка была отмечена на удаление:

```
QVariant TableModel::headerData(int section
    , Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {

    switch(orientation) {
        case Qt::Horizontal:
            return _d->headerColData(section).value(role);

        case Qt::Vertical: {
            if(role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
                QPersistentModelIndex pmi(this->index(section,0));
                if(_d->_inserted_pmis.contains(pmi)
                    || _d->_edited_pmis.contains(pmi))
                    return QString("*");

                if(_d->_removed_pmis.contains(pmi))
                    return QString("!");
            }

            return _d->headerRowData(section).value(role);
        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

Вставка значения ячейки заголовка:

```
bool TableModel::setHeaderData(int section
    , Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant &value, int role) {

    switch(orientation) {
        case Qt::Horizontal: {
            _d->headerColData(section)[role] = value;
            emit headerDataChanged(orientation, section, section);
            return true;
        }

        case Qt::Vertical: {
            _d->headerRowData(section)[role] = value;
            emit headerDataChanged(orientation, section, section);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Переопределение флагов ячеек таблицы с тем, чтобы стало возможным редактирование их значений. По умолчанию ячейки неизменяемы.

```
Qt::ItemFlags TableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
    if(index.isValid()) flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    return flags;
}
```

Возврат значения ячейки. Если пользователь её редактировал, то возвращаем значение из соответствующего списка, иначе значение берём из хранилища модели:

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    QVariant data;
    if(_d->_edited_cells.contains(QPersistentModelIndex(index))) {
        data = _d->_edited_cells[QPersistentModelIndex(index)].value(role);
    } else {
        data = _d->data(index.row(),index.column()).value(role);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Установка значения ячейки:

```
bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index
    , const QVariant &value, int role) {

    if(flags(index).testFlag(Qt::ItemIsEditable)) {
        QPersistentModelIndex pmi(this->index(index.row(),0));

        // Если ячейка принадлежит ранее добавленной строке,
        // то просто меняем значение ячейки прямо в хранилище.
        if(_d->_inserted_pmis.contains(pmi)) {
            _d->data(index.row(),index.column())[role] = value;
            emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);

        } else {
            // Если ячейка принадлежит отмеченной на удаление строке,
            // то отменяем удаление строки.
            if(_d->_removed_pmis.contains(pmi))
                _d->_removed_pmis.remove(pmi);

            // Добавляем строку ячейки в список
            // отредактированных пользователем строк.
            if(!_d->_edited_pmis.contains(pmi))
                _d->_edited_pmis.insert(pmi);

            // Новое значение ячейки размещаем в соответствующий список,
            // не трогая данные в хранилище модели.
            _d->_edited_cells[QPersistentModelIndex(index)][role] = value;
            emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Остаётся применение изменений и их отмена:

```
void TableModel::submitAll() {
    beginResetModel();
    _d->_inserted_pmis.clear();

    QHashIterator<QPersistentModelIndex,Cell> itr(_d->_edited_cells);
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        itr.next();

        const QPersistentModelIndex &pmi = itr.key();
        for(Cell::ConstIterator itr2 = itr.value().begin()
            ; itr2 != itr.value().end(); ++itr2) {
            _d->data(pmi.row(),pmi.column())[itr2.key()] = itr2.value();
        }
    }

    _d->_edited_cells.clear();
    _d->_edited_pmis.clear();

    foreach(const QPersistentModelIndex &pmi, _d->_removed_pmis)
        _d->removeRows(pmi.row(), 1);

    _d->_removed_pmis.clear();

    endResetModel();
}

void TableModel::revertAll() {
    beginResetModel();
    _d->_inserted_pmis.clear();
    _d->_edited_pmis.clear();
    _d->_removed_pmis.clear();
    _d->_edited_cells.clear();
    endResetModel();
}
```

Импорт данных в модель может быть осуществлён, например, посредством сериализации.