# Использование индексов в собственной табличной модели

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, qtcreator

Краткий экскурс: В качестве изучения Qt решил разобраться с MVC, сделав довольно простенькую программу, которая бы находила определенный штрих-код в таблице csv, которую загружает пользователь, и проделывала бы кое-какие определенные операции.
В основе изучения у меня лежат книга по Qt Шлее, документация и несколько сайтов в том числе стак. И по мере всего этого изучения и чуть-чуть практики скопилось много вопросов. Собственно, ближе к делу:
Я понимаю, что такое модель, представление, адаптеры, модельные индексы и +- как всё это взаимодействует друг с другом с помощью сигналов и слотов, НО при реализации своей простейшей модели, наследованной от QAbstractTableModel, столкнулся со следующим:
В книге в качестве примеров реализованы простейшие классы, например, модель для списка целых чисел IntListModel, в которой данные хранятся в односвязном списке `QList<int> m_list` и инициализируются соответствующе, а метод `data()` при валидном индексе возвращает `m_list.at(index.row())`. А в примере же реализации табличной модели TableModel данные хранятся в ассоциативном контейнере `QHash<QModelIndex, QVariant> m_hash` и никак не инициализируются, потому что метод `data()` реализован так:

```
// Проверка на валидность индекса (пропущу)
QString str = QString("%1, %2").arg(index.row() + 1).arg(index.column() + 1);
return (/* Проверка роли */)
? m_hash.value(index, QVariant(str)) : QVariant();
```

Само собой такое меня не устраивает, поскольку данные мне нужно хранить (не совсем, но об этом далее). В своём же классе-модели данные я храню в обычном одномерном векторе `QVector<QVariant> m_cells`, который инициализирую `m_cells{m_rows * m_cols}` и для проверки пушу тройку значений в него в теле конструктора класса:
`m_cells.push_back(13);
 m_cells.push_back(14);
 m_cells.push_back(15);`
Дальше начинается самое интересное:
Методы `rowCount()` и `columnCount` я реализую стандартно `return m_rows;` и `return m_cols;` соответственно. А вот метод как реализовать метод `data()` я никак не допру) Если пробовать как в первом примере в книге через `index.row()` - не прокатит, поскольку там метод `rowCount` возвращает `m_list.size();`, а у меня таблица, в которой есть столбцы и их нужно учитывать:
[image: Неправильный результат]

Пробовал создать не одномерный, а двумерный вектор
`QVector<QVector <QVariant> >`
и возвращать `m_cells[index.row()][index.column()]` но выдает ошибку:

> ASSERT failure in QVector::at: "index out of range"

Посмотрел в интернете и нашел вот такой вариант: [Реализация табличной модели с возможностью удалённой синхронизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533756/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
но я бы хотел разобраться пока со взаимодействием модели непосредственно с контейнером, ибо это намного проще.
1. Как мне лучше реализовать метод `data()` и почему не работают мои способы?
2. Почему при первом способе данные отображаются так, как отображаются?
3. В какой момент времени временные индексы удаляются?
4. Хоть они и являются лишь средством для простоты управления расположением элементов, можно ли как-то, используя индексы, записывать с помощью них информацию? Например, когда в книге использовался хэш, как бы я мог заносить в него данные, если ключом являются индексы?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что:
1. Модельные индексы создаются во время создания объекта класса модели функцией `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex()` (как написано в документации) и получают информацию о количестве строк и столбцов модели с помощью функций
`rowCount()` и `columnCount`?

Comment: У вас assert из-за методов rowCount и columnCount. Не храните отдельно размеры, возвращайте m_cells.size() и m_cells.empty() ? 0 : m_cells.front().size().
Само собой нужно следить, чтобы количество колонок во всех строках было одинаковое.

Comment: @UnrealReality А что касается остального?